# Disallow query strings in robots.txt for only one url

Tags: seo, web-crawler, search-engine, robots.txt, search-engine-bots

so I have one url, `chickens.com/hatching` that has potential query strings it could be indexed with, i.e. `chickens.com/hatching?type=fast`.  I would definitely like to keep the base url, `chickens.com/hatching` indexed, but no query parameters. I would like query parameters indexed on other pages, just not this one, so a catchall for all pages will not work. Secondarily, I am rewriting urls to remove trailing slashes, would this catch `chickens.com/hatching/?type=fast` as well as `chickens.com/hatching?type=fast`??

Does this work as a solution to my issue?

```
Disallow: /hatching?*
```

I have heard this only works for google crawlers... is there a more robust solution for all crawlers?

Thanks for any help! It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use canonical tags https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /hatching?
Disallow: /hatching/
```

This robots.txt will block all URLs whose path starts with `/hatching?` or `/hatching/`, so for example:

- `/hatching?`
- `/hatching?foo=bar`
- `/hatching/`
- `/hatching/foo`
- `/hatching/?foo=bar`

It’s only using features from the original robots.txt specification, so all conforming bots should be able to understand this.